# Disk Utility has no mounted disks in Mac recovery mode

Tags: macos, hard-drive, recovery

When I start up Mac in recovery mode, none of the disks are mounted and when I try to install Mac OS, there are no disks to install it on. The disks are there, but for some reason they will not mount.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are there filesystems that you expect to be mounted?  Run Disk Utility, select **View >> Show All Devices**, and erase the drive.  Then add a single HFS partition.  Then run the installer.